# Azure function can not access Azure Blob

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to access the storage account from the Azure function. But I get a 403 error when trying to retrieve the file. I don't see any problem with why I am getting this error.

Let me explain the setup.

1- Azure function app resides in east-US
2- Azure blob in South Central
3- Azure blob has the firewall enabled (I have enabled azure service can access)
4- I have also whitelisted the IP of the function app. (properties-virtual IP)
5- Azure function can create a blob client and retrieve all properties successfully.
6- If I enable the Azure Storage firewall public access, the function can download the stream.

any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: you can use azure function system identity to get access to blob storage, check this short tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-msi

Comment: are you using access keys or azure ad auth ?

Comment: Are you still facing the problem ?can you please provide more details related to the error /issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you have given it some time to work. It may take up to 12-13 hours for the storage account to whitelist a virtual network.

Else Function app might have problem to reach out services due to reasons below.

1. Your function app is hosted in an [internally load balanced App
   Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-ilb-ase) and it's configured to block inbound
   internet traffic.
2. Your function app has [inbound IP restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options#inbound-access-restrictions) that are
   configured to block internet access. Refer [app behind firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account#app-is-behind-a-firewall)

Otherwise

- Code may have worked locally as you may have added your local IP into
  White List  while this step was omitted for Function.
- Check if any outbound Ip missed out to add in whitelist Ips. On
  portal, go to Resource Explorer >under Platform features. Search
  outboundIpAddresses and add those(usually four) IPs into Storage
  Account White List.
- The issue may even be  because of a firewall being set on the
  storage. Disable it and it should work.

Other Work arounds

1. To enable firewall on storage account, one may have  to use vnet
   integration on storage account and App Service.See [virtual network
   integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options#virtual-network-integration). But it may work through selection of consumption
   plan for different regions and App service plan for same regions.
2. Also check for DNS configuration as existing Azure services are
   configured to use an existing DNS to connect to the public endpoint.
   You must override the DNS configuration to connect to the private
   endpoint. check  [private-endpoint.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint)
3. You can add network security to an Azure storage account by
   restricting access with a firewall and firewall rules.
   [grant-access-to-trusted-azure-service.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-to-trusted-azure-services)
   Check if any of the above is the issue in  your case.